# Terraform azurerm 2.x Error: "features": required field is not set

Tags: azure, terraform

So azurerm updated to 2.0 a few hours ago....

My main code is version locked for safety, but
I'm doing some testing to see what's changed from the public beta of 1.44 and now I'm getting this error on any TF command apart from terraform init.

has anybody else come upon this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

OK,
running terraform in debug mode showed it was at the provider level that the error was being thrown.

It's not listed in the 2.0 upgrade guide but if you look at the provider docs it now shows a features{} block.

So at a minimum the provider now needs to look like:

```
provider "azurerm" {
   features {}
}
```

Comment: This fixe worked. Looks like this is being discussed here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5867

Comment: Any other breaking changes? :s

Answer (score 0):

You could also fix the azurerm provider version to the last stable version 1.44:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.44"
}
```

Comment: Yes, you could, however, you would not then be able to use the new features that 2.0 gives.  It is however always good practice to pin to a version.

Comment: While pinning the version in production is always a good idea, the question here was specifically for version 2.0. So that answer has not much value for the question asked.

Comment: Can't use this with terraform versions > 0.14.0